# WiX installation into nested folder

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I want to install my application by default according to schema:

> Program Files/Company Name/Product Name

I write in WiX script:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationRoot" Name="Company Name">
      <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="Product Name">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Then all components are targeted to APPLICATIONFOLDER. However, setup installs files into

> Program Files/Company Name/

What is wrong?

Comment: I think we need to see some more of the source to be sure what is going on. You must have some mismatched identifiers.

Comment: @Stein Åsmul, thank you. I m not exactly sure, if it will be relevant to cite here full script, which is quite big. I will go through other fragments, which might be related to this context. I basically thought that directory structure is defined in exactly one location shown above.

Comment: It is probably just a DirectoryRef pointing to the wrong folder or something like that. It probably points to ApplicationRoot rather than APPLICATIONFOLDER. Just a guess.

Comment: Show your `DirectoryRef` that directs the storing of the files to the correct component. It is totally relevant. You don't have to show all of it if "it is quite big". But it is what decides where to store things, not the `Directory` structure itself, which is all you are currently showing.

Comment: Since APPLICATIONFOLDER is a property perhaps it is getting changed to that other ProgramFiles location. The declaration by itself means nothing because UI or custom actions can change it.

Comment: @PhilDW thank you. Due to your guidance i explored UI definitions and found there a property "ApplicationFolderName", which pointed to the wrong folder and override my directory definition. I see the latest hint as most relevant to resolve my problem.